# Can I randomise the start of the animation in an Instanced object?

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes, instances, random

I'm making a scene with a submarine like corridor, and there are multiple revolving siren like lights.

The issue is they're all spinning at the same time and it's not realistic, but I don't want to have multiple copies of the same geometry in the scene as it's quite heavy.

What I would like to do is take the rotating emissive part in the linked file and have it spin at a constant speed, but it's rotation start on a random frame, so that every copy would be slightly out of sync with the other.

I do have other instanced objects where I've made material node groups to change their colour at random with each instance, but I think this would be a Geometry Nodes thing and I don't really know what to do with those, only "what I'd like to do".

Any help, either with Geonodes or another method would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you make the color change? To me, this question seems to be more about a shader than geometry nodes. If you do the color change with a driver or keyframe you can just add *Object Info > Random* as an offset to create different colors for the instances.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this node setup here:

[image]

result:

[image]